# synchronize two sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, synchronization

I need to synchronize two sql server 2005 instances between intranet and extranet (through a firewall). Synchronization will be initiated from the intranet. What solutions do I have at my disposal?

intranet db: table t1 -> extranet db: table t1

intranet db: table t2 <- extranet db: table t2

i.e. intranet t1 content should be pushed out to extranet t1 
and intranet t2 content should be fetched from extranet t2.

We intend to sync every hour.

Comment: You should add information on wether you plan on migrating schema, data or both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replication, log-shipping, backup/restore, export/import.  All depending on your requirements.

Based on just shipping tables, I would just use SSIS.